# Procedimiento Almacenado que devuelva un valor entero

Tags: vb.net

Tengo el siguiente código y lo que deseo hacer es que al preguntar mediando un Procedimiento Almacenado, que si tengo un registro en especifico en mi Base de Datos y me devuelva un valor entero y como usar ese valor entero en Visual Basic, he estado leyendo foros, pero no encuentro mi duda, de antemano muchas gracias.

```
CREATE PROC PAValidarUsuario
    @Usuario varchar(30),
    @Contrasena varchar(30),
    @TipoUsuario varchar(15),
    @Valor int output
    as
    if exists(select * from TBUsuario where Usuario=@Usuario and Contrasena=@Contrasena and TipoUsuario=@TipoUsuario)
    begin
        set @Valor=1
    end
    else
    begin
        set @Valor=2
    end
```

Y Este es la Funcion de mi Visual Basic

```
Public Function ValidarUsuario(ByVal Datos As CUsuario)
    Try
        Conectado()
        CMD = New SqlCommand("PAValidarUsuario")
        CMD.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        CMD.Connection = Conexion
        CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Usuario", Datos.GetUsuario)
        CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Contrasena", Datos.GetContrasena)
        CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TipoUsuario", Datos.GetTipoUsuario)

        If CMD.ExecuteNonQuery Then
            Dim Num As Integer
            Num = ...
            'En ese Num, quiero obtener lo que retorne de mi Procedimiento Almacenado, pero no doy con el código
            Return Num
        Else
            Return Nothing
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Return Nothing
    End Try
End Function
```

Por favor, decirme los errores o que debo cambiar, muchas gracias.

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! El titulo tiene que ser representativo de sobre que es la pregunta. Y si muestras el codigo que tienes en VB, podemos ayudarte. Ese SP esta perfecto asi como esta.

Comment: Falta definir el parametro de salida.... y  solo te falta ejecutar el sp.. algo como.. cmd.executescalar (por ejemplo...) u otra similar.

Comment: Hola @gbianchi, gracias por tomar de tu tiempo atención en mi pregunta, ¿podrías proporcionarme algún ejemplo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Public Function ValidarUsuario(ByVal Datos As CUsuario)
        Try
            Conectado()
            CMD = New SqlCommand("PAValidarUsuario")
            CMD.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            CMD.Connection = Conexion
            CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Usuario", Datos.GetUsuario)
            CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Contrasena", Datos.GetContrasena)
            CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TipoUsuario", Datos.GetTipoUsuario)
            CMD.Parameters.Add("@Valor", SqlDbType.Int)
            CMD.Parameters("@Valor").Direction = ParameterDirection.Output)

            If CMD.ExecuteNonQuery Then
                Dim Num As Integer
//                Num = ... 'En ese Num, quiero obtener lo que retorne de mi Procedimiento Almacenado, pero no doy con el código
              Num = Int.Parse(CMD.Parameters("@Valor").Value.ToString())
            Else
                Return Nothing
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
            Return Nothing
        End Try
    End Function
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias Luciano Montañez